# Cron job sending bulk emails at a same time

Tags: php, cron, bluehost

I have a php script that generates output. I have created a cron job in bluehost to receive that in am email once a day. Previously it was working fine. but from last 2 days I am receiving 8 emails at same time.

If I am running the script then I am receiving only 1 email , but if I am executing it through cron job then I am getting bulk emails.
Any idea, why it is happening??

[image]

check out this image. IT shows how I added the cron job

Comment: have you set your cron job running once a day?

Comment: Post your cronttab entry to understand.

Answer (score 0):

yes please check in your `cpanel` again that it is only set for once a day or not..
it should be like

`0 22 * * *`
this code will execute your cronjob 10pm once a day...